# Django rest framework browsable API default url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]

How do I change the http://127.0.0.1:800/.. url? Is there a setting for it?

Comment: localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000 is the default server address when you execute `python manage.py runserver`. If you want to change it run `python manage.py runserver 127.1.1.2:5000` or any address:port combination to want. If you want to use domain names, you have to configure your `/etc/hosts` (if you use linux) and map you address with the domain name.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I realized I should be looking into my apache configuration, not django-rest-framework's